# MySQL Reserved Keyword

Tags: mysql, keyword

I'm having an issue with this query...

```
SELECT account_id FROM `clock`
 WHERE account_id = '.$accountId.' AND `clock`.`in` > 0 AND `clock`.`out` == 0
```

The only thing I can think of is that in/out are keywords.... but with backticks it should work fine.... right?

Comment: What issue?  What are you expecting the account ID to match?

Comment: No, he's probably getting a syntax error about the `==`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a double equals there mate '=='

change it to a single '='.